# Create Chrome and Firefox Plugins with Cordova Browser Target

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is it possible to generate a Cordova app as a Chrome extension and/or Firefox addon (both for the desktop)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is, however if I was wanting to do an app on the desktop I would maybe explore: http://electron.atom.io/

I have had REALLY good luck maintaining an app that uses essentially the same JS codebase for Cordova (Android, iOS) and Electron (OS X, Windows Desktop)